# I have finished the layout design (html & css), what should i do to convert it to a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

http://www.faressoft.org/BlueCristalTheme

And

http://www.faressoft.org/BlueCristalTheme/postView.php

What is the next step ?

Comment: Perhaps this is more appropriate for [DocType](http://doctype.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development among other docs at wordpress.org

Comment: ahjasdksajk you're 10 seconds faster +1